# Saving Model is cascading update when I only want the main model updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern, automapper-2

I am using C# Web API and I am using the repository standard to save to the database.  Below is a shortened example I am using to update the database.  So I use automapper to flatten between user to getuser the region.  So when I try to update for example the username using the UpdateUser model.  I use automapper to map from updateuser to user.  When I try to save it always gives me errors with updating Region.  I believe I need the region in the User model because I need it to automap between User to getUser and get the region.

I do not want to update region.  I am not understanding how to move forward from this.  Let me know if I am going about this ok and what the solution is.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}

public class GetUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    Public String Region{get; set;}
}

public class UpdateUser
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public String username { get; set; }
    Public String RegionID{get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doing some more research.  I found that the below automap would ignore region in the automap so the user has the region pulled from the database.  Is this the recommended way?  Below is what I am using for the automap:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<UpdateUser, User>().ForMember(x => x.Region, opt => opt.Ignore());
```